Email Public Group via flow in Lightning
I am trying to set up a flow so that when an object is created an email is sent out to all the users in a public group. So far I have the below:


I know that the loop variable is supposed to go after this but I am not sure how it functions. Can someone please assist?

Welcome to SF Stack Exchange.
I think your first two steps are a good start, just make sure you select the option to store "All Records" for your group member query. After that, you would need to get the emails for each group member, which are stored in the user record. That means you need to query the user records next. So yes, this is where the loop comes into play. You'll need to loop through all GroupMember records, and within the loop use an Assignment element to add the UserId of each GroupMember record to a text collection variable, for example "userIdCollection". Then, query all users whose Id is In userIdCollection and store all those user records. Lastly, you'll loop over the user record collection and within it use an assignment element to add the email of each user to a text collection variable, such as "emailCollection". Then you have a text collection variable with a list of emails to contact.
In summary (including what you've already done):

Query Group (you get a single record)
Query all GroupMember records (you get a record collection)
Loop over GroupMembers
Within loop, add each GroupMember.UserId to UserIdCollection (text collection variable)
Query all Users whose Ids are IN UserIdCollection (you get a record collection)
Loop over Users
Within loop, add each User.Email to emailCollection (text collection variable)
Send your email to emailCollection

With all that being said, I think it might be worth looking into using a Queue instead if you haven't already and/or it applies for your use case. There is a built in feature for queues where new record creations assigned to that queue automatically email all members of a queue.
Hope that helps.

what happens if a GroupMember is a Group? then you have to recurse

I was trying to do the same and found this resource helpful-- it offers the clearest step-by-step explanation I have found so far: https://thesalesforcetutorial.blogspot.com/2024/06/send-email-to-members-in-public-group.html
